# Failed to load image using stbi_load (lwjgl used)

Tags: kotlin, lwjgl

I'm learning OpenGL following [this](https://youtu.be/u-00hjlfMKc) video. While it's based on C++, I attempt to use Kotlin instead with lwjgl. As I code and run this:

```kotlin
// Something above
stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true)

val width = IntBuffer.allocate(1)
val height = IntBuffer.allocate(1)
val colorChannel = IntBuffer.allocate(1)
val imageBuffer = stbi_load(
   "src/main/resources/$filePath",
   width, height,
   colorChannel, 0
) ?: throw NoSuchElementException(filePath)
// Something below
```

It explodes on `stbi_load()` outside JVM with the following error message:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00007ff98391456e, pid=3740, tid=0x0000000000004e94
#
# JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_302-b08) (build 1.8.0_302-b08)
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.302-b08 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [lwjgl_stb.dll+0x456e]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   https://github.com/corretto/corretto-8/issues/
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000001f98ec0c000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=20116, stack(0x000000b726100000,0x000000b726200000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000200, RBX=0x000000b7261fed00, RCX=0x000000b7261fec90, RDX=0x000001f98ebc0000
RSP=0x000000b7261febb0, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x000001f9b823d040
R8 =0x000000b7261fd438, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x000000b7261fd650
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x0000000000000001, R14=0x0000000000000000, R15=0x0000000000000000
RIP=0x00007ff98391456e, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000b7261febb0)
0x000000b7261febb0:   000001f9b6031d00 000000b700000000
0x000000b7261febc0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000b7261febd0:   000000b7261fed38 00007ff983953854
0x000000b7261febe0:   000001f9b602e730 ffffffffffffffff
0x000000b7261febf0:   000000b7261fed00 0000000000000000
0x000000b7261fec00:   0000000000000000 000001f9b823d040
0x000000b7261fec10:   0000000000000008 000000b7261fed38
0x000000b7261fec20:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000b7261fec30:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000b7261fec40:   0000000000000000 00007ff983914a9c
0x000000b7261fec50:   000001f900000000 000001f9b602e730
0x000000b7261fec60:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000b7261fec70:   000001f900000000 000000b7261fec90
0x000000b7261fec80:   000001f900000008 00007ff9839539b8
0x000000b7261fec90:   0000000000000008 0000000000000000
0x000000b7261feca0:   000001f98ec0c000 000000b7261fef00 

Instructions: (pc=0x00007ff98391456e)
0x00007ff98391454e:   24 20 48 8b cf 75 07 e8 26 0d 00 00 eb 05 e8 9f
0x00007ff98391455e:   11 00 00 89 6b 0c 48 8b f8 48 85 c0 74 56 8b 03
0x00007ff98391456e:   41 89 04 24 8b 43 04 41 89 07 4d 85 f6 74 0d 8b
0x00007ff98391457e:   43 08 41 89 06 eb 05 48 8b 74 24 58 48 8b ce ff 


Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000200 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000b7261fed00 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f98ec0c000
RCX=0x000000b7261fec90 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f98ec0c000
RDX=0x000001f98ebc0000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000b7261febb0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f98ec0c000
RBP=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x000001f9b823d040 is an unknown value
R8 =0x000000b7261fd438 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f98ec0c000
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000b7261fd650 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x000001f98ec0c000
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R14=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value


Stack: [0x000000b726100000,0x000000b726200000],  sp=0x000000b7261febb0,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage.nstbi_load(JJJJI)J+0
j  org.lwjgl.stb.STBImage.stbi_load(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;Ljava/nio/IntBuffer;I)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+64
j  net.peanuuutz.graphics.Texture.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;IIII)V+67
j  net.peanuuutz.graphics.TexturesKt.main()V+328
j  net.peanuuutz.graphics.TexturesKt.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+0
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000001f9ac15a000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13668, stack(0x000000b727600000,0x000000b727700000)]
  0x000001f9ac0c0000 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=16976, stack(0x000000b727500000,0x000000b727600000)]
  0x000001f9ac0be000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20156, stack(0x000000b727400000,0x000000b727500000)]
  0x000001f9ac0b9800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=24508, stack(0x000000b727300000,0x000000b727400000)]
  0x000001f9ac0b6800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20268, stack(0x000000b727200000,0x000000b727300000)]
  0x000001f9ac0b3000 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3656, stack(0x000000b727100000,0x000000b727200000)]
  0x000001f9a9b9d000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3060, stack(0x000000b727000000,0x000000b727100000)]
  0x000001f9a9b9c800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11092, stack(0x000000b726f00000,0x000000b727000000)]
  0x000001f9a9b67000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14844, stack(0x000000b726e00000,0x000000b726f00000)]
  0x000001f9a9b60800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=23064, stack(0x000000b726d00000,0x000000b726e00000)]
=>0x000001f98ec0c000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=20116, stack(0x000000b726100000,0x000000b726200000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000001f9a9b39000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000b726c00000,0x000000b726d00000] [id=7040]
  0x000001f9ac15e000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000b727700000,0x000000b727800000] [id=11348]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

heap address: 0x00000006c2600000, size: 4058 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Zero based, Oop shift amount: 3
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 3
Compressed class space size: 1073741824 Address: 0x00000007c0000000

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 75776K, used 23537K [0x000000076b780000, 0x0000000770c00000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 65024K, 36% used [0x000000076b780000,0x000000076ce7c680,0x000000076f700000)
  from space 10752K, 0% used [0x0000000770180000,0x0000000770180000,0x0000000770c00000)
  to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x000000076f700000,0x000000076f700000,0x0000000770180000)
 ParOldGen       total 173568K, used 0K [0x00000006c2600000, 0x00000006ccf80000, 0x000000076b780000)
  object space 173568K, 0% used [0x00000006c2600000,0x00000006c2600000,0x00000006ccf80000)
 Metaspace       used 9236K, capacity 9501K, committed 9600K, reserved 1058816K
  class space    used 786K, capacity 879K, committed 896K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x000001f99fc60000,0x000001f9a0450000] byte_map_base: 0x000001f99c64d000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000051011820
 Begin Bits: [0x000001f9a09a0000, 0x000001f9a4908000)
 End Bits:   [0x000001f9a4908000, 0x000001f9a8870000)

Polling page: 0x000001f98eb80000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=2896Kb max_used=2896Kb free=242864Kb
 bounds [0x000001f9908a0000, 0x000001f990b80000, 0x000001f99f8a0000]
 total_blobs=1554 nmethods=665 adapters=802
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 0.513 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000  661       3       java.lang.Thread::isInterrupted (6 bytes)
Event: 0.513 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000 nmethod 661 0x000001f990b70e10 code [0x000001f990b70f80, 0x000001f990b71110]
Event: 0.513 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000  662       3       sun.nio.ch.Util$BufferCache::get (164 bytes)
Event: 0.514 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000 nmethod 662 0x000001f990b71190 code [0x000001f990b71380, 0x000001f990b71ed0]
Event: 0.514 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000  663       3       sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl::read (8 bytes)
Event: 0.514 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000 nmethod 663 0x000001f990b72390 code [0x000001f990b72500, 0x000001f990b72690]
Event: 0.514 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000  665       3       java.util.WeakHashMap::put (162 bytes)
Event: 0.514 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000 nmethod 665 0x000001f990b72750 code [0x000001f990b72980, 0x000001f990b73820]
Event: 0.514 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000  664   !   3       sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream::read (95 bytes)
Event: 0.515 Thread 0x000001f9ac0c0000 nmethod 664 0x000001f990b73e50 code [0x000001f990b74040, 0x000001f990b74af0]

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (2 events):
Event: 0.166 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Uncommon trap: reason=null_check action=make_not_entrant pc=0x000001f9909b55cc method=java.lang.String.equals(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z @ 8
Event: 0.192 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Uncommon trap: reason=unstable_if action=reinterpret pc=0x000001f990a362fc method=java.lang.String.indexOf([CII[CIII)I @ 3

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c26b4a8) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c26b8a0) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c26d940) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c26dd38) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c26fdd8) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c2701d0) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c272198) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.235 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'java/security/PrivilegedActionException'> (0x000000076c272590) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp, line 1523]
Event: 0.334 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x000000076c325c70) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 711]
Event: 0.334 Thread 0x000001f98ec0c000 Exception <a 'sun/nio/fs/WindowsException'> (0x000000076c3276b0) thrown at [C:\wsjdk\Corretto8Src\installers\windows\zip\corretto-build\buildRoot\src\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp, line 711]

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.507 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GL$ICDStatic$WriteOnce
Event: 0.507 loading class org/lwjgl/opengl/GL$ICDStatic$WriteOnce done
Event: 0.507 loading class net/peanuuutz/graphics/Texture
Event: 0.507 loading class net/peanuuutz/graphics/Texture done
Event: 0.507 loading class org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage
Event: 0.507 loading class org/lwjgl/stb/STBImage done
Event: 0.508 loading class org/lwjgl/stb/LibSTB
Event: 0.508 loading class org/lwjgl/stb/LibSTB done
Event: 0.516 loading class java/nio/HeapIntBuffer
Event: 0.516 loading class java/nio/HeapIntBuffer done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6c0390000 - 0x00007ff6c03ca000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff9bc240000 - 0x00007ff9bc430000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff9bbe70000 - 0x00007ff9bbf22000     C:\windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff9b9660000 - 0x00007ff9b9903000     C:\windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff9baee0000 - 0x00007ff9baf83000     C:\windows\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9bab50000 - 0x00007ff9babee000     C:\windows\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff9ba5e0000 - 0x00007ff9ba677000     C:\windows\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff9baf90000 - 0x00007ff9bb0b0000     C:\windows\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff9bbf30000 - 0x00007ff9bc0c4000     C:\windows\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff9ba2c0000 - 0x00007ff9ba2e1000     C:\windows\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff9bb130000 - 0x00007ff9bb156000     C:\windows\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff9b9450000 - 0x00007ff9b95e4000     C:\windows\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff9b92b0000 - 0x00007ff9b934e000     C:\windows\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x00007ff9b9350000 - 0x00007ff9b944a000     C:\windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff9a7010000 - 0x00007ff9a7295000     C:\windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.657_none_e6c5b579130e3898\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff9bb8c0000 - 0x00007ff9bbbf6000     C:\windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff9b9230000 - 0x00007ff9b92b0000     C:\windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff9badd0000 - 0x00007ff9badfe000     C:\windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ff97c2b0000 - 0x00007ff97c39f000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\msvcr120.dll
0x00007ff997140000 - 0x00007ff9971e6000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\msvcp120.dll
0x0000000050820000 - 0x0000000051090000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff9bb0b0000 - 0x00007ff9bb0b8000     C:\windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff9b36d0000 - 0x00007ff9b36da000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff9b5a80000 - 0x00007ff9b5a89000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff9aaac0000 - 0x00007ff9aaae4000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff9bb0c0000 - 0x00007ff9bb12f000     C:\windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff9ab070000 - 0x00007ff9ab09d000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\winmmbase.dll
0x00007ff9b95f0000 - 0x00007ff9b963a000     C:\windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x00007ff9b4cd0000 - 0x00007ff9b4cdf000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x00007ff99cc00000 - 0x00007ff99cc29000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\java.dll
0x00007ff99b8c0000 - 0x00007ff99b8ea000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x00007ff9a8a50000 - 0x00007ff9a8a66000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff9bb1d0000 - 0x00007ff9bb8b5000     C:\windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff9bae10000 - 0x00007ff9baeb9000     C:\windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ff9b99f0000 - 0x00007ff9ba16f000     C:\windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ff9b9120000 - 0x00007ff9b913f000     C:\windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff9b9180000 - 0x00007ff9b91ca000     C:\windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff9b9110000 - 0x00007ff9b9120000     C:\windows\System32\UMPDC.dll
0x00007ff9ba680000 - 0x00007ff9ba6d2000     C:\windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ff9b9160000 - 0x00007ff9b9171000     C:\windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff9b9640000 - 0x00007ff9b9657000     C:\windows\System32\cryptsp.dll
0x00007ff99cc70000 - 0x00007ff99cc8a000     D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\bin\breakgen64.dll
0x00007ff9a7ef0000 - 0x00007ff9a7f0a000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ff9ac1f0000 - 0x00007ff9ac210000     C:\windows\system32\PrxerDrv.dll
0x00007ff9b8980000 - 0x00007ff9b89e7000     C:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x00007ff9a4930000 - 0x00007ff9a4942000     C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ff985d30000 - 0x00007ff985da2000     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgl<User>\3.2.2-build-10\lwjgl.dll
0x00007ff987630000 - 0x00007ff98768e000     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgl<User>\3.2.2-build-10\glfw.dll
0x00007ff9b7100000 - 0x00007ff9b7199000     C:\windows\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x00007ff995400000 - 0x00007ff995443000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dinput8.dll
0x00007ff99b530000 - 0x00007ff99b541000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\xinput1_4.dll
0x00007ff9b8f10000 - 0x00007ff9b8f3a000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x00007ff9b7520000 - 0x00007ff9b754d000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x00007ff99b700000 - 0x00007ff99b81a000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\inputhost.dll
0x00007ff9b55e0000 - 0x00007ff9b56cf000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\PROPSYS.dll
0x00007ff9b6df0000 - 0x00007ff9b6ec4000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CoreMessaging.dll
0x00007ff9a4240000 - 0x00007ff9a456a000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\CoreUIComponents.dll
0x00007ff9b4b70000 - 0x00007ff9b4cc3000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll
0x00007ff9bbda0000 - 0x00007ff9bbe64000     C:\windows\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x00007ff9b8170000 - 0x00007ff9b81a1000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntmarta.dll
0x00007ff9ba4a0000 - 0x00007ff9ba5d5000     C:\windows\System32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ff9b7d20000 - 0x00007ff9b7d2e000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL
0x00007ff9ba6e0000 - 0x00007ff9bab50000     C:\windows\System32\SETUPAPI.DLL
0x00007ff9b99c0000 - 0x00007ff9b99e6000     C:\windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
0x00007ff9b91d0000 - 0x00007ff9b922c000     C:\windows\System32\WINTRUST.dll
0x00007ff9b9140000 - 0x00007ff9b9152000     C:\windows\System32\MSASN1.dll
0x00007ff9ba170000 - 0x00007ff9ba2b9000     C:\windows\System32\CRYPT32.dll
0x00007ff99a6e0000 - 0x00007ff99a836000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\opengl32.dll
0x00007ff9acfd0000 - 0x00007ff9acffc000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll
0x00007ff9b7df0000 - 0x00007ff9b7e10000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll
0x00007ff96e170000 - 0x00007ff96f020000     C:\windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_d9c21d7d43c1adb3\ig9icd64.dll
0x00007ff9b7e10000 - 0x00007ff9b7efb000     C:\windows\system32\dxgi.dll
0x00007ff99f200000 - 0x00007ff9a11c8000     C:\windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_d9c21d7d43c1adb3\igc64.dll
0x00007ff9a1280000 - 0x00007ff9a139a000     C:\windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\iigd_dch.inf_amd64_d9c21d7d43c1adb3\igdgmm64.dll
0x00007ff99ccd0000 - 0x00007ff99cd6e000     C:\windows\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
0x00007ff9ac3e0000 - 0x00007ff9ac686000     C:\windows\System32\iertutil.dll
0x00007ff986790000 - 0x00007ff9867e8000     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgl<User>\3.2.2-build-10\lwjgl_opengl.dll
0x00007ff983910000 - 0x00007ff98398f000     C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Local\Temp\lwjgl<User>\3.2.2-build-10\lwjgl_stb.dll
0x00007ff9b7a40000 - 0x00007ff9b7c34000     C:\windows\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -javaagent:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=58472:D:\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1\bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
java_command: net.peanuuutz.graphics.TexturesKt
java_class_path (initial): C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Users\<User>\.jdks\corretto-1.8.0_302\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\Everyday\Amateur\CS\Kotlin\Exercises\Graphics\build\classes\kotlin\test;E:\Everyday\Amateur\CS\Kotlin\Exercises\Graphics\build\classes\kotlin\main;E:\Everyday\Amateur\CS\Kotlin\Exercises\Graphics\build\resources\main;D:\Cache\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.4.32\461367948840adbb0839c51d91ed74ef4a9ccb52\kotlin-stdlib-1.4.32.jar;D:\Cache\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl\lwjgl-assimp\3.2.2\d4128312444099cea3c4dbb77f5098d19e340d\lwjgl-assimp-3.2.2.jar;D:\Cache\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl\lwjgl-glfw\3.2.2\d3ad4df38e400b8afba1de63f84338809399df5b\lwjgl-glfw-3.2.2.jar;D:\Cache\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.lwjgl\lwjgl-openal\3.2.
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;D:\Python\Python39\Scripts\;D:\Python\Python39\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64_win\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\Minecraft\´´×÷\µØÍ¼\¹¤¾ß\WorldPainter;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.12\bin;D:\Git\cmd;D:\MySQL\bin;D:\gradle-6.8.3\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;E:\Minecraft\Replay\.minecraft\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\Minecraft\´´×÷\µØÍ¼\¹¤¾ß\WorldPainter;E:\Minecraft\Replay\.minecraft\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;E:\Minecraft\´´×÷\µØÍ¼\¹¤¾ß\WorldPainter;E:\Minecraft\Replay\.minecraft\FFmpeg\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intel\Shared Libraries\redist\intel64\compiler;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\window;D:\Visual Studio Code\Microsoft VS Code\bin;D:\PyCharm 2020.3\bin;;C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\npm;D:\Fiddler
USERNAME=<User>
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 158 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 10.0 , 64 bit Build 18362 (10.0.18362.329)

CPU:total 12 (initial active 12) (6 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 158 stepping 13, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx

Memory: 4k page, physical 16614584k(6470396k free), swap 25527480k(11553304k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.302-b08) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.8.0_302-b08), built on Jul 15 2021 19:37:21 by "Administrator" with MS VC++ 12.0 (VS2013)

time: Thu Oct 07 16:20:51 2021
timezone: ?D1¨²¡À¨º¡Á?¨º¡À??
elapsed time: 0.532927 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)
```

The image is [here](https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/Red%20rubble%20ch16.png)(png, 512px), and I've saved it in the (maybe) correct place as the code shows.

**So what is going on in the native environment? :(**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LWJGL 3 does not support on-heap (i.e. *non-direct*) NIO Buffers when talking to a native library like stb_image. Non-direct/on-heap NIO Buffers are those that are wrappers of a Java byte array.

With LWJGL 3 you *always* need to use off-heap (i.e. *direct*) NIO Buffers.

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#direct for a further explanation of the differences.

So, instead of

```java
IntBuffer.allocate(1)
```

you should use:

```java
ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4).asIntBuffer()
```

Also you should configure the NIO Buffer to use the same endianness as your platform, since otherwise you will read garbage out of the buffer later (the default endianness of all NIO Buffers is network-byte-order i.e. big endian):

```java
ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asIntBuffer()
```

and since the above is quite a mouthfull, LWJGL 3 provides a [`BufferUtils`](https://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.html) class with simple wrappers, like:

```java
BufferUtils.createIntBuffer​(1)
```

to achieve the same as above.

And last but not least, doing correct and efficient memory management in LWJGL 3 is more involved, because in this particular case, you'd be better off using a `MemoryStack`.
See: https://blog.lwjgl.org/memory-management-in-lwjgl-3/